# How to prevent distortion after straightening UV?

Tags: texturing, texture-baking

Distortion occur after straightening my UV. I use UV square  and  "Align UV + follow active quad" method. Usually is not much of a problem, but this time I am trying to create a pattern

As you can see from the image provide, the pattern is a bit distorted

[image]
[image]
[image]

Are there way to overcome this ?

Or is there other ways to create such pattern. Currently, I bake the one small part of the pattern to a plane (2048x2048) and then arrange the baked normal  in a straight line if Photoshop. Is there a better way to approach this ?

[image]

Comment: See what you get if you subdivide a bit

Comment: ok, just tried it.  it looks better. But this was intended to be a low poly model...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the quads are deformed between the object and the UV Editor, the image is deformed as well, we can see the inside triangulation of the face, to fix that you need to subdivide with a *Subdivision Surface* modifier so that the deformation becomes unnoticeable.

If you need to stay low poly, duplicate your object A, subdivide object B with a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, plug its normal map directly into the *Output* and bake the *Emit* into a new copy (object C) that you've unwrapped (with a simple *Unwrap* mode this time):

[image]

Result of the bake, now you can use this map as normal map of object C:

[image]

Comment: @Moonbot. thank you. that exactly what I need.